# Bug in std::sort?

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, segmentation-fault

OK, I typically default to assuming that the error is in my code, but what I am seeing is making literally no sense to me.

---

I have a `std::vector<DocumentWidget *>`, which I want to be sorted by some relatively simple algorithm. Here's what I am seeing.

The code looks like this:

```
std::vector<DocumentWidget *> documents = DocumentWidget::allDocuments();

// NOTE(eteran): on my system, I have observed a **consistent** crash
// when documents.size() == 17 while using std::sort.
std::sort(documents.begin(), documents.end(), [](const DocumentWidget *a, const DocumentWidget *b) {

    int rc = (a->filenameSet_ == b->filenameSet_) ? 0 : a->filenameSet_ && !b->filenameSet_ ? 1 : -1;
    if (rc != 0) {
        return rc < 0;
    }
    if(a->filename_ < b->filename_) {
        return true;
    }
    return a->path_ < b->path_;
});
```

Seems simple enough, but it crashes specifically when I have a 17th item in the list! The sorting predicate clearly is not modifying the `vector` in any way, so I can't see that being an issue. Address sanitizer and valgrind show no errors up until this point.

`qSort` **does not crash**, seems to work fine. No other threads that are running are touching this data, and it happens reliably no matter how slowly I step... so it's not a race condition.

When I look in the debugger, the `a` parameter seems to be where the "one past the end" iterator is pointing. But that shouldn't be happening if `std::sort` is behaving [image: Crash].

**Note** There are 17 items in the `std::vector`, I forced the debugger to display an 18th item to illustrate where `a` seems to be coming from.

I can't imagine that `std::sort` is bugged, but I am really struggling to find another explanation. Am I missing some obvious bug here?!

Comment: `if(a->filename_ < b->filename_) { return true; }` should likely come with the converse. You can end up with both `a < b` and `b < a`.

Comment: Try `return std::tie(a->filenameSet_, a->filename_, a->path_) < std::tie(b->filenameSet_, b->filename_, b->path_);`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
if(a->filename_ < b->filename_) {
    return true;
}
return a->path_ < b->path_;
```

This is known as "not a valid strict weak ordering":

```
{ "a", "d" } < { "b", "c"}; because "a" < "b"
{ "b", "c" } < { "a", "d"}; because "c" < "d"
```

The fix is simple: don't reinvent the wheel:

```
return std::tie(a->filename_, a->path_) < std::tie(b->filename_, b->path_);
```

Comment: The logic of `filenameSet_` can also be tied (assuming it is a `bool` and not a pointer of sorts).

Comment: @TravisGockel Yes. I sort of dislike using `<` on `bool`s, but then the convoluted comparison code in the OP isn't that much better.

Comment: Definitely a lose-lose scenario.

Comment: @T.C. I agreed that the code is a bit convoluted. This is part of a port of a very old codebase, and I wanted to start with using the same exact behavior the original code had. `std::tie` seems to do the job perfectly.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

@T.C.'s answer is a good one since the question is tagged C++11, but in case future readers are after a C++03 solution, the 'canonical' way to write such a comparison operator (for members m1, m2, .... mn) is

```
if (a->m1 != b-m1)
    return a->m1 < b->m1;
else if (a->m2 != b->m2)
    return a0>m2 < b->m2;
else ...
else if (a->mn != b->mn)
    return a->mn < b->mn;
else
    return false;
```

(see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7781941/canonical-relation-operators) for a discussion, with the question having the above style but avoiding operator!=).

One further thing is that you are using pointers and your code is not bomb-proof. If `a` or `b` is NULL you'll get a crash. If you can't avoid pointers and you want to be paranoid then you need to add checks like

```
if (!a && !b)
    return false;
else if (!a)
    return true;
else if (!b)
    return false;
```